# Newtonsoft JSON schema compare containing object type

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, jsonschema

I have a model like the one described below.

```
public class QueryValueDataModel
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public QueryValueType ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

I have a JSON serialization of QueryValueDataModel type:

```
{
   "Value": 100,
   "ValueType": 0
}
```

When I compare the schema of the JSON object with the QueryValueDataModel schema

```
var obj = JToken.Load(reader); 

IList<ValidationError> errorMessages = new List<ValidationError>();
SchemaExtensions.IsValid(obj, schema, out errorMessages)
```

I get an error and the schema don't match:

`Invalid type. Expected Object, Null but got Integer`

How can I deal with this situation and make the schema comparison work? Or alternately, is there some workaround for it?

Comment: Why is `Value` of type `object` in the class? What kind of different types do you want to support here?

Comment: The all primitive types

Comment: string, integer, float, double....

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSchemaGenerator to create JSchema from any object and compare it with JObject.IsValid() method

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(QueryValueDataModel));
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonstr);
if(o.IsValid(schema))
{
    QueryValueDataModel deserialized = o.ToObject(typeof(QueryValueDataModel));
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("schema dosn't match");
}
```

Please note! JSchemaGenerator has been moved to Newtonsoft.Json.Schema nuget package.

[image]